# Parse string to json that contains backslash

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

How can I parse this string to JSon:

```
{"quest": "<span katex='\left \{ \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \right \}'></span>"}
```

using JSON.parse(str) , I get this error:

```
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token l
```

Comment: Why the double- and single-quotes are overlapping? How did you generate this object?

Comment: It was my mistake! Now It is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is already a valid JSON object.

```
var obj = {"quest": "<span katex='\left \{ \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} \right \}'></span>"}

console.log(obj.quest);
```

If you want to retain a backslashes, you should do:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.quest));
```

Comment: If you copy and paste the string in a online tools like [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/)  you will get the error.

Comment: I did it and everything seems to be fine. See my updated answer.

Comment: The string is already generated using JSON.stringify(). Using JSON.parse() I get  the error.

Comment: the problem come from your online tool

Comment: @vitozev : `console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));` to be correct.

Comment: When I delete all backslashes it will be Ok. But I don't want delete them.

Comment: @Beheshti You don't have to ! but your online tool can't work correctly ! if you want to use it you have to remove or double them !

Comment: @Beheshti copy and paste this in your online tools : `{"quest": "<span katex='left \\{ \\sqrt{n+1}-\\sqrt{n} \\right \\}'></span>"}`